# How likely is a 2 or 3 years old laptop giving slow performance as compared to when it was new?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, gaming

My laptop is 3 years old (i7 8th generation with 940MX 4GB GDDR5 RAM and 8+8 GB RAM).

I never got the hardware inside cleaned professionally. And I used it almost daily for at least 12 hours. In other words, my laptop is on 12-15 hours a day since the day I bought it.

---

**Why I think there's something wrong with my laptop:**

I saw many videos on YouTube where they play many games even on medium to high settings at 1280x720 resolution and still get at least 30 FPS most of the time.

What surprises me here is that they use slightly older generation of processors like i5 6th generation and i7 6th generation with same 940MX GPU (with 2GB GDDR5 variant). So GPU is same just the memory is half which I really don't think makes any difference for this GPU.

However, my laptop gets 30 FPS only when I run game at 800x600 to 1024x768 resolution with below medium settings. For same games. So I really think there's something wrong.

---

I tried to find some solutions to fix it like fresh installing Windows again *(Windows is in SSD drive and games are also in same drive)*. It made no difference.

I never played any heavy games during first 2 years of this laptop so I really can't comment how was the performance of new laptop.

---

Recently I read that it might happen because your laptop wasn't cleaned from inside like dust and other things. Also, maybe thermal paste has 'expired'. So maybe the dust and heating issues slow my laptop more than ever.

**How likely is that given I've used the laptop a lot and never cleaned the inside of my laptop professionally and never checked the condition of thermal paste?**

Comment: Get some software and monitor the heat and CPU frequencies and that may help guide you towards finding the problem.

Comment: 2 years of heavy use probably means you need to look at cleaning, replacing thermal pads, and potentially checking fans are running okay.  Laptops tend to accumulate and hold on to dust.

Comment: @davidgo okay. I'll try that. Any way to find the ideal heat and frequencies for my laptop? So that I can evaluate better with those software?

Comment: One way wpuld be to look at the cpu specs - for example on intel ark if itd an intel cpu.  I expect mkst software would also tell you the max  cpu speed.

Comment: Is your laptop on battery or plugged in when your attempting to game?

Comment: Plugged in always. It isn't a ppwsr issue for sure @cybernard

Comment: Did you check your power plan, under power options in the control panel?  Is it set to **High performance** or **Ultimate Performance**?

Comment: @cybernard I've tried both. My laptop don't have Ultimate option. I have tried Balanced which is default settings. Then Power saving and High performance. They make no difference.

Comment: @davidgo I tried a software. CPU temperatures were around 80-90 degree C. But GPU Clocks were fixed at 405 MHz. It reached around 1000 MHz when game just starts. But after that it is showing constatnt 405 MHz. https://imgur.com/gSpBnIb

Comment: I don't know if that's default behavior or something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How likely is a 2 or 3 years old laptop giving slow performance as
> compared to when it was new?

In the majority of cases, this is not at all likely.

I have had a desktop computer running here 24 hours a day since XP. Different computers over time. These computers did not slow down. Newer computers (newer designs) are, of course, faster.

> I never got the hardware inside cleaned professionally.

Ordinary dust does not cause a computer to slow down. A very dusty environment might - have it serviced or clean it yourself.

I have never needed to replace thermal paste in a decent computer.

> So I really think there's something wrong.  I tried to find some
> solutions to fix it like fresh installing Windows again (Windows is in
> SSD drive and games are also in same drive). It made no difference.

Two things:

(a) if you think there is a hardware problem, have the computer serviced.

(b) It is feasible the computer is not as fast as you recall. A fresh install of Windows on a properly operating computer will run as fast as the computer could ever run.

If you want a faster computer, it may be time for a new one designed for the games you wish to run.

Comment: _"Ordinary dust does not cause a computer to slow down."_ actually it's not uncommon at all in laptops. Dust buildup can clog their narrow vents and lead to thermal throttling.

Comment: It depends. All environments have some dust and I have not seen many machines slow down because of this. Heavy dust - maybe as I noted in my answer

Comment: Hi. I remember last time Dell technician came to my home to replace its keyboard. One year ago. I vaguely remember he removed each and every part including the heatsink part. He didn't apply new paste at that moment. Just assembled all parts again after replacement.

Maybe my laptop became slow after. Is it possible?